# How do I execute code before <body> gets printed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written some code that parses the HTML of a page, and replaces certain words with links. The script is called from just before the `</head>` tag.

The problem is when placed in pages where there are scripts embedded in the `<body>`. When this script replaces the `body` HTML, these scripts are executed again, and in some cases some crazy things can happen (like loops).

**How can I adjust my code so it does all its replacement work before `<body>` is printed and executed?**

```
function linkify_words(id)
{
  const url = `http://localhost:4000/js/linkify_words.json/${id}`
  $.get(url, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        linkify($("body"), value[1], value[0])
    })
  })
}

function linkify(parent, regex, url) {
  var children = parent.children("div,p,li,ul,ol,span")
  const re = RegExp(`(${regex})(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)`,"ig")
  children.each(function() {
    linkify($(this), regex, url)
  })
  parent.html(parent.html().replace(re, `<a rel="nofollow" href="${url}">$1</a>`))
};
```

Comment: You can't, when those scripts run the body does not exist yet

Comment: Is there any way to address the issue of preventing <body> embedded scripts getting run twice when <body> gets replaced by my script?

Comment: Plus the `$.get` is asynchronous .

Comment: Consider hiding the body with CSS. You can then run your DOM operations when the DOM is available, and reveal the body after that.

Comment: A tricky way would be to add SetTimeout on the body and put visibility hidden or opacity:0 and then after your changes are done you can put the opacity back to 1

Comment: @DavidHedlund but surely that is only cosmetic? Any JS in the body would still run, even if it was invisible?

Comment: Not a good practice to replace whole body html. Can have event listener issues also

Comment: @cjm2671: Yes, sorry, I just realized what you were going for here. In that case, consider not replacing the entire body, but only the elements to be linkified themselves.

Comment: Understood, I'll seek out <p> tags and attack those alone.

Comment: Thank you everyone!